# How to get different substring of a filed in Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to get substring set of a field in Django model. the data format like this

```
1, 20001, a
2, 20002, a
3, 21002, a
4, 51003, b
5, 51001, a
```

I only want to get first two charactor of the second column with distinct: `[20, 21, 51]`

How can I get the result using django model function?

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: Does your function have to return a list? If not, you can use set to store all the values since a set would automatically get rid of the duplicates. Then you can just convert it back to list before returning or just let it be.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (replace {field_name} with the name of your field):

```
def first_two_digits(self):
    return int(str(self.{field_name})[:2])
```

It transforms the integer you get into a string, cuts it to only get the first 2 chars, and converts it again into an integer.

EDIT: 
There is an alternative way if you know that you'll always get numbers with 6 digits:

```
def first_two_digits(self):
    return self.{field_name} % 10000
```